# Ubuntu 15.10 server wifi and Atheros AR9287

Tags: networking, drivers, server, 15.10, atheros

I have a server I am trying to get wifi working on...it cannot be wired due to the location it needs to be in. I bought an TP-Link TL-WN881ND for it seeing that it had the same chipset (Qualcom Atheros AR9287) which I saw on thinkpenguin (bought the TP-Link from Amazon for quick shipping)...anyway, it connects to my WPA2 wifi network, but I cannot ping the router, resolve dns internally or externally. It is using the following driver:

```
ath9k
```

I have tried anything that made sense when googling, including adding the following:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

but no change. I have installed the full ubuntu gnome desktop to try anything to get it working...when trying via command line before installing desktop, I attempted to get it working via wpa_supplicant, but it would hang after issuing the following:

```
wpa_supplicant -iwlp3s0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext
```

which I guess is a generic wireless driver...ath9k was never listed there, just nl80211. I'm not finding anything on 15.10 and the ath9k issue. Anyone able to help?

EDIT: I am able to run a temporary ethernet cable to try stuff...it's just...temporary :(

Answer (score 0):

Just to update, I re-installed to 14.04 LTS and was able to get it working using wpa-supplicant typical configuration...probably best to stick with LTS on a server anyhoo.